# Multi-user finguerprint registration and detection in windows hello

Tags: uwp, multi-user, visual-studio-2017, windows-hello

I'm using Windows 10 and VS2017.I have a Fingerprint sensor and Windows hello installed and working fine. It detects fingers.

I'm now developing a UWP app for multiuser registration using fingerprint.
For that propose Im using following part of code:

```
 var keyCreationResult = await KeyCredentialManager.RequestCreateAsync(
                               ("Peter",
                                KeyCredentialCreationOption.ReplaceExisting);
```

The problem I found is that it currently shows a UI dialog asking for current logged in user credentials confirmation. It was suppose to show after this the Windows Hello Settings page for fingerprint detection (as is in the normal Windows 10 "Windows Hello" Settings page).

After logged in user confirmation the dialog closes and no further fingerprint detection is possible, I don't know is this is a Security norm from Microsoft to not allow outside settings finger detection?! .

Please can someone test this line of code and let me know if problem confirms?

And how to correctly use multi-user fingerprint registration and detection?

Comment: As far as I known, `Finguerprint` can not be used for multi-user fingerprint registration and detection.

Comment: Thank you for comment this, but I think if library exists for that propose, as is in above text, it should be possible to do so.